# Can someone with a blemish be king?

Tags: halacha-theory, malchut-royalty, handicap-disabled-impair

I saw somewhere recently that when Tzidkkiyahu was blinded, he was invalidated from hypothetically returning to rule over Judea as king, because he now had a halachic blemish (מום). Is this true, that someone with a blemish cannot be king?

Comment: I think I saw the same thing regarding the king who was punished with tzaraas for doing the avodah.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE On the contrary, Uzziyahu was still king for the rest of his life (and those years are counted towards his reign).

Comment: @Meir Happy to be corrected, it was a vague recollection

Answer (score 5):

The Rambam in Hilchot Melachim ([chapter 1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188345/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-1.htm)) lists a number of conditions to be a king (not to be a convert, a woman, a butcher, barber, bath-attendant or a tanner). Having no blemish is **not** such a condition.

In addition, the Tanakh ([Shmuel II 14:25](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.14.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) mentions Absalom was without blemish. If this was a mandatory condition to being a king, it wouldn't need to be mentioned.

As such, it appears to me that someone with a blemish can be a king.

Comment: I went through the whole of hilchot melachim before posting this question, but was unsure what the lack of references to blemishes meant.

Comment: Did David become a bath attendant by observing Bathsheba?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Chasam Sofer (שו״ת אורח חיים סימן י״ב), a king may not have a blemish, based on Yevamot 101 and Kiddushin 76b regarding the Sanhedrin “and above”